# How to go from one view to first view of storyboard in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to i phone programming.can aby body tell me How to go from one view to storyboard first view.Below code is firstviewcontroller.m class there i have taken one button inside that i have written some action which i want to go from firstviewcontroller to first view fisrt view of stroyboard.

```
 #import"firstviewcontroller.h"  
    -(IBAction)show:(id)sender
    {
     UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
     LXCollectionViewController *Controller = [storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Controller "];
      [self presentModalViewController:loginController animated:YES];

    }
```

Below code is storybord firstview code how can i go from this xib view to storyborad view.programatically.above code is not working.

```
     #import "LXCollectionViewController.h"
        #import "PlayingCard.h"
        #import "PlayingCardCell.h"
        @implementation LXCollectionViewController
        - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
        {
            self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
            if (self) {
                // Custom initialization
            }
            return self;
        }
        - (void)awakeFromNib {
            [super awakeFromNib];
            self.deck = [self constructsDeck];
        }

        - (NSMutableArray *)constructsDeck {
            NSMutableArray *theDeck = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:52];
            for (NSInteger theRank = 1; theRank <= 13; theRank++) {
                // Spade
                {
                    PlayingCard *thePlayingCard = [[PlayingCard alloc] init];
                    thePlayingCard.suit = PlayingCardSuitSpade;
                    thePlayingCard.rank = theRank;
                    [theDeck addObject:thePlayingCard];
                }
            }
            return theDeck;
        }

        - (void)viewDidLoad {
          //  NSLog(@"%@",theDeck);
            [super viewDidLoad];
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }
        #pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource methods

        - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)theCollectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)theSectionIndex {
            switch (theSectionIndex) {
                case 0: {
                    return [[self valueForKeyPath:@"deck.@count"] integerValue];
                } break;
                default: {
                    return 0;
                } break;
            }
        }

 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)theCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)theIndexPath {
                NSInteger theSectionIndex = theIndexPath.section;
                NSInteger theItemIndex = theIndexPath.item;
                switch (theSectionIndex) {
                    case 0: {
                        PlayingCard *thePlayingCard = [self.deck objectAtIndex:theItemIndex];
                        PlayingCardCell *thePlayingCardCell = [theCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PlayingCardCell" forIndexPath:theIndexPath];
                        thePlayingCardCell.playingCard = thePlayingCard;
                        return thePlayingCardCell;
                    } break;
                    default: {
                        return nil;
                    } break;
                }
            }

            #pragma mark - LXReorderableCollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout methods

            - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)theCollectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)theLayout itemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)theFromIndexPath willMoveToIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)theToIndexPath {
                id theFromItem = [self.deck objectAtIndex:theFromIndexPath.item];
                [self.deck removeObjectAtIndex:theFromIndexPath.item];
                [self.deck insertObject:theFromItem atIndex:theToIndexPath.item];
            }
```

Above code in IBAction is not working.Please tell me how to connect form xib to firstview of storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

try below one if you are using iOS sdk 6.1 as `presentViewController` is deprecated

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
LXCollectionViewController *objController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Controller"];
[objController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[self presentViewController:objController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and also make sure that you have specified identifier in storyboard's viewControllers

Comment: thanks for giving replay.Now also its not working specified identifier in storyboards view controllers means.Acctually i am using collectionview controller in story board.